# Command working at the command line but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, t-sql

I have a shell script that I'm running that is not quite working as expected. When it is run manually at the command line, it works perfectly and does everything I expect. Once it is put into a script, the results disappear.

Here is what I'm running:

```
result=`/bin/echo "$query" | /usr/local/bin/tsql -S $server -p $port -U $user -P $pass -o fhq 2> output`
```

The case where the login fails and errors are written to output works perfectly in the script, but when the login is successful and results are returned, nothing is set to result.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your command is directing the results (stdout) to a file named `output`. The errors (stderr) are not being redirected, so when there is an error they are captured in the `result` variable.

Comment: Only connection errors are sent to output, I did check that just to be safe.

Comment: Yes, actual database related errors are not considered problems as far as the `tsql` command is concerned.

Comment: If you want the results, check the `output` file or stop redirecting to `output`.

Comment: The results do not get written to output. I've run this at the command line with success and I know what is expected in the script. If the login fails, the failure is written to output. If the login is successful, the results are set to "result." I did remove the redirect as a test to see if that was the cause and it didn't fix it. I also checked output to see if the results are there and they were not.

Comment: Maybe you didn't catch that there is a 2 in "2> output" that is redirecting the stderr and not the stdout.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When you run it at the command line, you also try storing the result in a variable?

Comment: Yes I am, I ran it exactly is shown above. I set all my variables to make sure it was exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: Try running the command within your script but without sending the result to a variable.

Comment: I tried that already, didn't make any difference.

Comment: Meaning when you ran the script, no results were printed to the console?

Comment: Correct. I also tried redirecting stdout to output and nothing was sent there either.

Comment: Them my guess is that your variables are not being set in your script. Try printing them from your script to make sure they have the values you expect.

Comment: All the connection variables are being set properly. I also removed the variables and hard coded the connection info into the command and still nothing was returned.

Comment: Figured it out. A variable that I believed was setting the history check to be 6 hours was only 1 and there was not supposed to be output. I guess that's what happens when you get stuck editing someone's code that isn't commented well. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it as mentioned below :

result=`/bin/echo "$query" | /usr/local/bin/tsql -S $server -p $port -U $user -P $pass -o fhq 2> output 1> success`